# Long string concatenation problem in java?

Tags: java

When I am trying to concatenate strings in Java like so:

```
COsavedform = vtd + "," + stricode + "," + striname+ "," 
            + striqty + "," + strirate + "," + striamt;
```

every variable containing some String Value and returns correct value of `COsavedform` but when I add something more to the same `COsavedform` like..

```
COsavedform = vtd+","+ccode.getText()+","+striqty 
            + "," + strirate + "," + striamt+","+mode+",Customer";
```

`mode` is also a string variable. Then it returns only `COsavedform=","+mode+",Customer"`, only not the entire things.
Problem part of that full code_--

````
        System.out.println("striname:"+striname);
        System.out.println("stricode:"+stricode);
        System.out.println("striqty:"+striqty);
        System.out.println("strirate:"+strirate);
        System.out.println("striamt"+striamt);
        System.out.println("ccode"+ccode.getText());
        System.out.println("mode"+mode);
                String Csavedform = vtd + "," + stricode + "," + striname+ "," + striqty + "," + strirate + "," + striamt;
                System.out.println("CSaved::"+Csavedform);
                //System.out.println("COSaved::"+COsavedform);
                String Isavedform = vtd+","+ccode.getText()+","+striqty+","+strirate+","+striamt+","+mode+",Customer";
                System.out.println("Item savedforitem::"+Isavedform);
                ```
Output Generated::
vdt:31/12/2019
striname:Kazu
stricode:kazu
striqty:1.0
strirate:1000.0
striamt1000.0
ccode0001
modePending
CSaved::31/12/2019,kazu,Kazu,1.0,1000.0,1000.0
,Pending,Customer



Output Expected::
vdt:31/12/2019
striname:Kazu
stricode:kazu
striqty:1.0
strirate:1000.0
striamt1000.0
ccode0001
modePending
CSaved::31/12/2019,kazu,Kazu,1.0,1000.0,1000.0
Item savedforitem::31/12/2019,0001,1.0,1000.0,1000.0,Pending,Customer
````

Comment: It's very hard to understand the question as its posted. Please share some sample data with the output you're getting vs the output you'd want to get.

Comment: THere is a `" +` before Customer in your 2nd example if that a typo ?

Comment: StringBuilder is way more readable and less prone to error. 
Try to convert this concatenation using `StringBuilder`

Comment: I updated with Output Generated and Output Expected

Answer (score 5):

You can use +=

```
COsavedform += vtd+","+ccode.getText()+","+striqty + "," + strirate + "," + striamt+","+mode+",Customer";
```

But better to use StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("str1").append("str2")... 
    COsavedform  = stringBuilder.toString();
```

because its better for memory

Answer (score 1):

**Use concat()**

Java string concat() method concatenates multiple strings. This method appends the specified string at the end of the given string and returns the combined string. We can use concat() method to join more than one strings

> **Edited Answer after comment**

There are  4 Ways to concatenate String in Java

Concatenation operator (+)
StringBuffer class
StringBuilder class
String.concat() function

**Use + operator to concatenate**

```
String stringA= "Stack"; 
String stringB = "overflow";
```

```
String result = stringA + "," + stringB; 
System.out.println(result);
```

**By using StringBuilder**

```
StringBuilder result  = new StringBuilder();
 result.append(stringA).append(",").append(stringB); 
 System.out.println(result.toString());
```

**By using StringBuffer**

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(); 
sBuffer.append(stringA).append(",").append(stringB); 
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: I tried but not working it as returned by above Mentioned code

Comment: I have edited the answer again please try to understand